Cell fracture addon replaced by Voronoi Texture?
Is cell fracture depreciated and replaced by Voronoi Texture now? I have seen lots of people using the Voronoi texture node approach on 3D objects but have not seen anyone use it to actually fracture a 3D mesh. Is this possible now without cell fracture?

Hello, IMO as this question is posted the answer can only be subjective and arbitrary. Could you elaborate on what exact features you think are deprecated ?

Apart from that I suppose you are just missing where to enable the add-on, which @Crantisz adresses in his answer, I'm not even sure what you are asking about. Cell Fracture is a tool to create a fractured object, the Voronoi Texture is, well, as the name says a texture which can be used in materials, displacement and Geometry Nodes...?

This add-on was not deprecated, but as other add-ons, bundled with Blender, now moved to the extensions platform:
https://extensions.blender.org/add-ons/cell-fracture/
See also:
About Blender Extensions Platform

Thanks for your reply. I guess I was asking if there is any other method besides the cell_fracture addon/extension which fractures a 3D mesh. I had seen voronoi_texture be used to create voronoi patterns, but had not seen it applied to 3D fracture geometry.
